# Google Directory API - 403 [Not Authorized to access this resource/api] on one machine, works on another

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client

I've been testing my authorization code and suddenly I started to get:

```
Not Authorized to access this resource/api [403]
Errors [
    Message[Not Authorized to access this resource/api] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]
```

I scratched my head and tried a few things but I didn't think I'd changed anything.  Eventually I tried running it on a different machine.  It worked without error.

I'm using v1.6 of the Google Directory API .NET Client.  I've been working on this for a while.  I had service authorization working and was working on client authorization when I experienced the issue.  I'm currently getting the same error when I try authorizing with service creds.  I'm not currently in a position to check if that process still works on the other machine.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm using the same ClientId on the two machines.

Comment: First place I would look at is the HTTP Headers.

Comment: Check that https://cloud.google.com/console/?api=admin (Admin SDK) is enabled

Comment: It is.  Strange: when I tried that URL, I got a 404 so I went to https://code.google.com/apis/console/ (which is what I've used previously) and it was redirected to cloud.google.com/console!

Comment: Could it be some throttling thing?  Could I have hit an authorization threshold for that machine?

Comment: Can you please provide the exact code you are trying to run? Do you use some GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone had taken my account out of the Admin role. The reason it worked on the other machine was I'd logged in with a different admin account that hadn't been 'house-kept'.   The names only differ by one character and I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a 403 error as well. I resolved it by correcting the permissions.  I had the project setup into Google under `xyz@company.com`:

1. I had to login as our super user into Gmail
2. search for user `xyz`
3. I selected the user, then pressed <kbd>Show more</kbd>
4. I clicked on `0 Admin roles and privileges`
5. enabled "User Management" since I was trying to pull a list of users

And the error went away.

Comment: If you're using a Google service account with domain-wide delegation, logon as a super admin and assign the service account to the User Management role.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post when receiving the same error.  I am not in an Admin role, but figured I should be able to see the basic User Profile since I can access it from Contacts.  After a little more research I came across this good piece of information: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#retrieve_users_non_admin

In a nutshell, set `viewType` parameter to `domain_public`

Here's what that looks like in C#

```
    var getRequest = directoryService.Users.Get(googleId);
    getRequest.ViewType = UsersResource.GetRequest.ViewTypeEnum.DomainPublic;  
    User directoryUser = getRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: Thanks @Airn your answer helped me

Comment: bydefault it set to `admin` :(

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread but none of the answers helped me... as it turns out I made a typo **in the domain name** of the group I was looking up... ‍♂️

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/gruop@sub.example.com
                                                             ^^
=> Error 404 "Resource Not Found: groupKey"

GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/group@sbu.example.com
                                                                  ^^
=> Error 403 "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
```

So if you get a 403 error, check to make sure it's not just a 404 error in disguise